# Using Parameters when Calling Script with Start-Job

Tags: powershell

I am working on a script that must change users in the middle of running in order to be able to access a network folder. I have figured out how to get the credentials working, but now cannot understand how to pass parameters to the second script that is being called. The code that I currently have:

```
$myJob = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {& "\\my\folder\path\script.ps1" -serverName $serverName -serverInstance $serverInstance} -Credential $cred
        $myJob | Wait-Job
        $myJob | Receive-Job -Keep
```

I need to pass the `serverName` and `serverInstance` variables to the script that `Start-Job` is running, while also still being able to use credential. Is there a way to do this?

I have investigated `Invoke-Command` and `Invoke-Expression`, but neither of those fit this situation. Invoke-Command doesn't work with remote computers/drives and Invoke-Expression doesn't work with credentials. I tried the answer that was provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52228193/powershell-start-job-with-a-scriptblock-calling-another-script-with-parameters), but that would not correctly pass in the parameters either.

Any help is much appreciated as I have been working on this problem for a few hours now. I am sure I am missing something obvious.

Comment: You can use the `using` keyword here: `-serverName $using:serverName -serverInstance $using:serverinstance`.

Comment: or `Start-Job -ArgumentList $var1,$var2 -ScriptBlock {$args[0],$args[1]}`

Comment: @AdminOfThings Awesome thank you! That worked perfectly. I have never come across `$using` so I have something new to research and learn about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `using` scope modifier provided you are on PowerShell version 3 or higher:

```
$myJob = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {& "\\my\folder\path\script.ps1" -serverName $using:serverName -serverInstance $using:serverInstance}
```

> You can also use local variables in remote commands, but you must indicate that the variable is defined in the local session. Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, you can use the Using scope modifier to identify a local variable in a remote command. The syntax of Using is as follows:
>   `$Using:<VariableName>`

If you are on PowerShell version 2, you will need to utilize the `-ArgumentList` parameter and then modify your scriptblock to accept the arguments that are passed. [Avshalom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4568320/avshalom) comments on one way to do this.

See [About_Remote_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-6) for more information.