# Get-WmiObject Win32_networkadapterconfiguration

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

I'm trying to use WMI to retrieve network adapter information on remote servers.

I've ran a few Get-WmiObject commands with various degrees of success.

This line works fine:

```
 Invoke-Command $serverName -ScriptBlock {Get-WmiObject 
 Win32_networkadapterconfiguration | where {$_.Index -eq 7}}
```

When I try to introduce a variable to the command it returns nothing:

```
 $Variable = 7
 Invoke-Command $serverName -ScriptBlock {Get-WmiObject 
 Win32_networkadapterconfiguration | where {$_.Index -eq $Variable}}
```

Any idea why the command with the variable would fail?

Comment: Swap `$Variable` with `$using:Variable` in the `where { }` statement. The reason is that the scriptblock knows nothing about variables in your current scope. The `$using:` scope modifier will make the mapping happen for you.

Comment: @AdminOfThings thank you! I'm sorry what exactly does the using keyword do to a variable?

Comment: See [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56451708/11025476) for an explanation.

Comment: You can also avoid the `Invoke-Command` entirely; just do `Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Computer $servername | Where-Object {$_.Index -eq $variable}` - this also bypasses the need to fiddle with `$using:`.